# Error al compilar MPI C++ en Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilador

El error es el siguiente:

> g++ "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\" -O0
>   -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\pt.o" "..\src\pt.cpp"  g++: fatal error: no input files

He de decir que he estoy trabajando en **Eclipse** sobre Windows 10 (porque no me queda otra) y tengo instalados los paquetes que contienen las bibliotecas necesarias para el compilado y ejecución de MPI de Microsoft (`msmpisdk.msi`y `MSMpiSetup.exe)`. El compilador es **MinGW** y tengo creadas todas las variables de entorno necesarias tanto del compilador como de **MSMPI**.

[image: CAPTURA]

Como se muestra en la imagen de arriba, las bibliotecas se encuentran bien sincronizadas porque todo está libre de error y me aparecen en el relleno automático del IDE todos los métodos y demás. Tiene que haber algo en la orden de compilación automática que no esté bien.

A continuación aparece la imagen de la configuración del compilador:

[image: compilador1]

Y ahora de los argumentos de compilado y linker:

[image: compilador2]

[image: compilador3]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tiene pinta de que la ruta `"..\src\pt.cpp"` no es correcta y el compilador no es capaz de encontrar ningun fuente a compilar

Comment: Gracias por contestar @eferion . Es la ruta que pone por defecto Eclipse, ahí no he tocado nada. El caso es que compila correctamente cuando le quito los includes relacionados con MPI. Pero claro, eso no me vale. La verdad es que es bastante raro y no sé por dónde meterle mano ya.

Comment: no deberías incluir las cabeceras de MPI en el proyecto sino que deberías definir rutas de inclusión. Mira la pestaña "Project References" de la configuración... ahí deberías meter las rutas de inclusión y los símbolos a importar de MPI (las librerías estáticas generadas)

Comment: No sé a lo que te refieres con que no debo de incluir las cabeceras de MPI en el proyecto @eferion . A esto `#include <mpi.h>`? 
En cuento a lo de "Project References", ahí solo me da la opción de elegir otro proyecto del workspace actual.

Comment: No, me refiero a añadir las cabeceras como archivos del proyecto. La MPI la deberías compilar como librería estática y enlazar dicha librería en tu aplicación. ¿por qué? Es más sencillo de gestionar y de acotar los posibles errores de compilación. De los includes no te libras, pero son cosas diferentes

Comment: y todo eso no se hace en la configuración que aparece en la última foto que he adjuntado? @eferion

Comment: No. Ahí estás configurando el formato de la compilación. En la pestaña que te he indicado en comentarios anteriores puedes añadir rutas de inclusión. Una ruta de inclusión le indica al compilador donde debe buscar los includes externos.

Comment: como ya te he comentado, en "Project References" solo me da opción de elegir proyectos incluidos en mi workspace, no hay una opción para lo de las rutas de inclusión @eferion

Comment: Mira la opción "_Paths and Symbols_". La pestaña "_Includes_" debería ser la que necesitas para añadir cabeceras de librerías de 3os (como MPI). La pestaña "_Libraries_" debería servir para añadir las librerías precompiladas.

Comment: No tengo eclipse ni MPI. Si funciona avísame y elaboro la respuesta correspondiente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58393/discussion-between-mario-rodriguez-and-eferion).